# Google cloud functions | A function with trigger onUpdate is getting called every time another with onCreate is triggered for realtime database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have two cloud functions in my code: one with onCreate and another with onUpdate trigger for realtime database on the same path.
Whenever a new data is added,the function with onUpdate also gets called. How can I prevent this?

```js
exports.createSdkUser = functions.database.ref("users/{app}/{user}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    ...
});


exports.updateSdkUser = functions.database.ref("/users/{app}/{user}").onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: of course its gonna be called since you added data to its watching spot which is the same document / path

Answer (score 0):

creating an `onUpdate()` function is just like setting a watcher event for that document ... if any data added or changed or deleted then the function will be executed ... you cant stop that from happening but you can condition what should be executed on that function and what shouldn't be by using conditions like :

```
  exports.updateSdkUser = functions
 .database.ref("/users/{app}/{user}")
 .onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  snapshot.forEach((snap)=>{
      if(snap.data().username) {
        // Do this if there is certain data in my database (for example : username)
      }else {
        // else just return don't do anything
        return;
      }
   })
  });
```